# Docker For Development Only

Tags: linux, docker, weblogic

I am an IT Supervisor head and have very little development background so I apologize for this naive question.
Currently, we are using Weblogic, running in Linux VMs, created by Oracle VM (OVM) to host our application for production.

The development environment also uses the same configuration.

Our developers are suggesting we use docker in the development environment and utilize DevOps to increase the agility of development.

This sounds like a good idea to me, but I still want our production to run on the same configuration running today (Weblogic in Linux VMs over Oracle VM Hypervisor); I do not want to use docker for production.

I have been searching to find out if that is possible with no luck.
I would really appreciate it if you can help.
I have three questions:

- Is that possible?
- Is that a normal practice to run docker for development only while using traditional nondocker for production?
- If it is possible, what are the best ways to achieve that?

Thank You

Comment: It is possible by hooking your source code to the application runtime container i.e. via the `-v` flag on your dev machine while using Docker.

Comment: You can we did that at one of our clients and they still use docker in dev and test while normal deployments in Prod. This has helped testers and developers launch a very customized environment combining 20-30 different microservices into a single one

Comment: This is a rather broad question and the kind of thing that takes some time to architect to properly describe how to accomplish. Basically the short answers are 1. yes, 2. yes but companies that focus on modern efficient methodologies to save time and money do PaaS deployments to streamline the image through the env lifecycles, and 3. most easily through container datacenter software like Docker Datacenter or Mesophere's DC/OS.

Answer (score 0):

Docker is linux distro-agnostic. Java development is JEE container-agnostic (if you follow the Java official specs defined in the JSRs).

So, these are two reasons why you should have the same behaviour between your developper environment and your production environment. Of course, a pre-production environment should be welcome to be sure this is true. And do not avoid looking at memory and performances issues, before doing that. Moreover, depending on the reason you are using Weblogic, ask yourself about which JVM and JEE container you would run in your docker containers.

> - is that possible ?

Yes, we do that in my organization, for some applications, using tomcat (instead of WebSphere for other applications).

> - is that a normal practice to run docker for development only while using traditional none docker for production ?

There are many practices, depending on the organization goals, strategy and level of agility. Using Docker for development and not in production is the most use-case with Docker containers, nowadays, but the next level is to use a Docker engine in a production environment. See next section:

> -if it is possible, what are the best practice to achieve that ?

**The difficulty is that in a production environment, you need a system for automating deployment, scaling, and management of containerized applications.**

Developers do not need that. So it is really easy for them to migrate to Docker (and it lets them do things easier and faster than without Docker).

In production, you should really consider using **[Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/)** or **[OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/)**, instead of running a simple docker engine, like your developers do. But it is much more complicated than simply installing Docker on a single Windows or Linux host.